# How to add MPMediaItem to MPMediaItemCollection

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I hope to play `MPMediaItemcollection` using `MPMusicPlayerController`.

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
```

I have got the handler of `MPMediaItem *mediaItem`.

How can I add `MPMediaItem` to `MPMediaItemCollection`? I try `addObject`, but no function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add items to an already created MPMediaItemCollection. Instead you have to add them when you create the collection, using `initWithItems:` or [`collectionWithItems:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemCollection_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008213-CH1-SW3).

You could "fake" adding an item by creating a new collection based off of the old one. Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myMediaItemCollection.items];
[items addObject:myNewMediaItem];
MPMediaItemCollection *myNewMediaItemCollection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:items];
```

(If your collections are going to live beyond the scope of the current method, you'll need to assign them to properties or call retain as appropriate.)